# Solve $(x^2+y^2+1)dy+xydx=0$

Tags: calculus

Solve $(x^2+y^2+1)dy+xydx=0$

I tried many times but I can't solve it

Answer (score 3):

make a change of variable $$ u = x^2 + y^2 + 1 \to du = 2x\, dx + 2y\, dy$$ 
we now have a separable differential equation for $u$. that is $$\frac{du}{dx} = 2x+2y\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x-2y\frac{xy}u=\frac{2x(u-y^2)}u = \frac{2x(x^2+1)}{u} $$
i hope you can take it from here.

Comment: I am understand, thankyou very much